# want to show hover style

Tags: html, css

I want to show hover style but in the output nothing is showing

This is my html page

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style rel="spreadsheet" type="text/css" src="hover_check.css">
    <title>hover effect</title>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="hover">
        <img src="java3.jpg">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css file is as follows

```
.hover .image {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow:visible;
    border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hover a.info {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px; /* Center the link */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}

.hover:hover .image {
    opacity: 1;
    border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.hover:hover a.image {
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

img {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
}
```

If I remove  my css link from the html page  then my image was visible.

Comment: Might be something overriding your css in that file. It looks working here http://jsfiddle.net/Y5hQB/

Comment: @shadow How to overcome that one.Can you please tell?

Comment: Please, if you have another question ask it in another post, but don't edit the original question because there's a valid answer already, and the future users that came here with a similar question may will be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that causing problem => `<style rel="spreadsheet" type="text/css" src="hover_check.css">`

Rewrite this line as: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="hover_check.css" />`, the styles will start working. Also close the `<head>` tag properly.

The final code should look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="hover_check.css" />
        <title>hover effect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hover">
            <img src="java3.jpg">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks freind..And one more help the effect when i hovering a image is showing under the image .I want that to be over the image

Comment: Check out this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Y5hQB/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5hQB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the `<head>` tag, you have open it two times ;)

Also, I think the correct markup to link a stylesheet is:`<link rel="stylesheet"....` not `<style rel="...`

[W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Here is a useful tool to validate your html, some errors come often from an incorrect markup. This tool alerts you that errors.

Comment: Try the second option I posted you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add head tag with **link** tag instead of style tag. Please check the code.

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../StyleSheet.css" />
    <title>hover effect</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hover">
        <img src="java3.jpg">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]